# turn list of depth first traversal nodes back into tree structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Given the following input (from a CSV file):

```
input = [
  { :level => 0, :value => "a"   },
  { :level => 1, :value => "1"   },
  { :level => 1, :value => "2"   },
  { :level => 2, :value => "I"   },
  { :level => 2, :value => "II"  },
  { :level => 2, :value => "III" },
  { :level => 0, :value => "b"   },
  { :level => 0, :value => "c"   },
  { :level => 0, :value => "d"   },
  { :level => 1, :value => "3"   },
  { :level => 1, :value => "4"   },
]
```

How can I convert this to the following in "The Ruby Way":

```
expected = [
  { :value => "a", :children => [ { :value => 1, :children => nil },
                                  { :value => 2, :children => [ { :value => "I", :children => nil },
                                                                { :value => "II", :children => nil },
                                                                { :value => "III", :children => nil } ] } ] },
  { :value => "b", :children => nil },
  { :value => "c", :children => nil },
  { :value => "d", :children => [ { :value => 3, :children => nil },
                                  { :value => 4, :children => nil } ] },
  ]
```

?

**Edited:**

My solution to this was to sidestep the problem, transform it and get someone else to solve it:

```
require 'yaml'
def linear_to_tree(a)
  yaml_lines = []

  a.each do |el|
    indent = " " * 4 * el[:level]
    yaml_lines << "#{indent}-"
    yaml_lines << "#{indent}  :value: #{(el[:value])}"
    yaml_lines << "#{indent}  :children:"
  end
  yaml_lines << ""  # without this, YAML.load complains
  yaml = yaml_lines.join("\n")
  # open("test_yaml.txt", "w"){|f| f.write(yaml)}
  YAML.load(yaml)
end
```

But there must be a more elegant way to solve this.

P.S. I'd also like to see a one-liner for this transformation, just to see if it's possible.

Comment: No, __someone else__ is the `Yaml` parser.

Comment: so these are basically ordered in "depth first" order?

Comment: Yes. (At least I think so from what I've seen of the CSV.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an empty array for nodes that have no children, an empty array is the null object for a collection. Otherwise you have to dance around both when you assign it, and when you use it.

```
def transform(inputs)
  transform! inputs.dup
end

def transform!(inputs, output=[], current_level=0)
  while inputs.any?
    input = inputs.shift
    level, value = input.values_at :level, :value
    value = value.to_i if value =~ /\A\d+\z/
    if level < current_level
      inputs.unshift input
      break
    elsif level == current_level
      next_children = []
      output << {value: value, children: next_children}
      transform! inputs, next_children, current_level.next
    else
      raise "presumably should not have gotten here"
    end
  end
  output
end
```